# App initialization error in neo4j desktop

Tags: windows, neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I installed neo4j desktop on my windows laptop. It works fine for a few days but the app does not launch after that. I tried reinstalling it a lot of times and the same thing happens - Works fine for a few days and then does not launch.

I see this error message in the neo4j logs everytime this error happens-

```
App initialization error: SyntaxError: Malformed JSON in file: C:\Users\Indra_K\.Neo4jDesktop\persist\projects.json
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 {
  constructor: 'SyntaxError',
  stack: 'SyntaxError: Malformed JSON in file: C:\\Users\\Indra_K\\.Neo4jDesktop\\persist\\projects.json\n' +
    'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0\n' +
    '    at FileAsync.parse [as deserialize] (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at C:\\Program Files\\Neo4j Desktop\\resources\\app.asar\\node_modules\\lowdb\\adapters\\FileAsync.js:41:35\n' +
    '    at async C:\\Program Files\\Neo4j Desktop\\resources\\app.asar\\dist\\main.prod.js:1:177229\n' +
    '    at async C:\\Program Files\\Neo4j Desktop\\resources\\app.asar\\dist\\main.prod.js:1:223470'
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Neo4jDesktop then remove these folders: C:\Program Files\Neo4j Desktopm and C:\Users\Indra_K.Neo4jDesktop then re-install Neo4jDesktop. It works for me before.

Comment: I have done this about 3-4 times. It resolves the issue for a few days and then again I get the same error.